# "fruit juice" vs "fruit juices" How can such liquid substance as "juice" be pluralized unless it is contained in a can, bottle etc.?

Tags: word-meaning, singular-vs-plural

While reading [this article](https://www.bangkokpost.com/business/1487426/health-concerns-demand-creative-response-from-juice-makers) from Bangkok Post.com, I noticed the word "juice" and its plural form "juices" are both used.

> Consumers have long regarded **fruit juice** as a healthy option,
> especially when compared to carbonated soft drinks. But many credible
> scientific studies have found that drinking **fruit juice** is not the
> same as consuming fruit, because some commercial **fruit juice**
> products contain as much sugar as soft drinks, sometimes even more.
>
> Such findings have been bad news for producers of mass-market **fruit
> juices**, as consumers are now looking for healthier alternatives.
>
>
>  ... Many of these writers have noted the misconceptions about the health
> benefits of **fruit juices** and warned about high sugar content in some
> brands.

It isn't difficult to guess from the context that the "fruit juices" probably refers to fruit juice products, but if that is the case, I thought the writer should have written so.

Collins Dictionary defines "[juice](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/juice)" and "[juices](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/juices)" as below.

> **Juice**:
> 1. Juice is the liquid that can be obtained from a fruit. 
> 2. The juices of a piece of meat are the liquid that
> comes out of it when you cook it.
> **Juices**: 
> 1. the liquid that comes out of a piece of meat when it is cooked 
> 2. the liquid that occurs naturally in or is
> secreted by plant or animal tissue

I wonder which one of the four definitions above is applicable to the "juices" described in the article.

Comment: You can pluralize a mass noun when you’re referring to two distinct masses. I like apple juice and orange juice; they are my favorite juice*s*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juice, like water, is *usually* uncountable, but it *can* be countable if used as a collective noun where there is more than one collection.

For example, the water in a glass is "some water". But when ordering two glasses of water, some might idiomatically ask for "two waters".

If you had a small amount of juice in a glass, or gallons of it, you could use "juice" to refer to it all. But if you had some orange juice, some pineapple juice, and some mango juice - you have three different juices. "Juice" then becomes a collective noun for each *type* of juice. Similarly, like my example with water, some may idiomatically order two glasses of juice by asking for "two juices".